# What is the meaning of the letters in the output from struct.pack?

Tags: python, pack

when i change number into hex in  struct module of python,

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack("i",89)
'Y\x00\x00\x00'
>>> struct.pack("i",890)
'z\x03\x00\x00'
>>> struct.pack("i",1890)
'b\x07\x00\x00'
```

what is the meaning of "Y,z,b"  in the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not converting to hex. You're packing the integer as binary data... in this case, little-endian binary data. The first characters are just the corresponding ASCII characters to the raw bytes; e.g. `89` is `Y`, `122` is `z`, and `98` is `b`.

- The first `pack` produces `'\x59\x00\x00\x00'` for `0x00000059`; `'\x59'` is `'Y'`.
- The second produces `'\x7a\x03\x00\x00'` for `0x0000037a`; `'\x7a'` is `'z'`.
- The third produces `'\x62\x07\x00\x00'` for `0x00000762`; `'\x62'` is `'b'`.

See the below ASCII table.

[image]
<sub>(source: [asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Note that you are not converting to hex, you are converting data to raw bytes. The console is then echoing those bytes back to you, in a form that can be entered again as python literal strings.

So python is printing the *literal byte string*, and some of the bytes can be represented as ASCII characters; most bytes in the range 0x21-0x7E can be printed as such:

```
>>> '\x22'
'"'
>>> '\x50'
'P'
```

Thus, 'Y', 'z', and 'b' are bytes that fall in that range and python just prints them as ASCII instead of `\x` escapes:

```
>>> '\x59'
'Y'
>>> '\x62'
'b'
>>> '\x7a'
'z'
```

The rest of your bytes fall outside of the printable ASCII range, so python is representing these as `\xFF` literals, which happens to use hex notation.

Answer (score 2):

lets go line by line
but first we have to understand little-endian format and char value:
**32 bit little-endian** int have the most significant bits on the right
so the value of the in memory hex (0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04) is really (0x04, 0x03, 0x02, 0x01) 
**char value** 'Y' = 0x59 = 89, 'z' = 0x7a = 122, 'b' = 0x62 = 98

'Y\x00\x00\x00' = 0x59, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 /Data in memory
'Y\x00\x00\x00' = 0x00000059  = 89 /Real integer value

'z\x03\x00\x00' = 0x7a, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00 /Data in memory
'z\x03\x00\x00' = 0x0000037a  = 890 /Real integer value

'b\x0b\x07\x00' = 0x62, 0x07, 0x00, 0x00 /Data in memory
'b\x0b\x07\x00' = 0x00000762  = 1890 /Real integer value