# Python: converting hex values, stored as string, to hex data

Tags: python, python-2.7, hex

(Answer found. Close the topic)

I'm trying to convert hex values, stored as string, in to hex data.

I have:

```
data_input = 'AB688FB2509AA9D85C239B5DE16DD557D6477DEC23AF86F2AABD6D3B3E278FF9'
```

I need:

```
data_output = '\xAB\x68\x8F\xB2\x50\x9A\xA9\xD8\x5C\x23\x9B\x5D\xE1\x6D\xD5\x57\xD6\x47\x7D\xEC\x23\xAF\x86\xF2\xAA\xBD\x6D\x3B\x3E\x27\x8F\xF9'
```

I was trying `data_input.decode('hex')`, `binascii.unhexlify(data_input)` but all they return:

```
"\xabh\x8f\xb2P\x9a\xa9\xd8\\#\x9b]\xe1m\xd5W\xd6G}\xec#\xaf\x86\xf2\xaa\xbdm;>'\x8f\xf9"
```

What should I write to receive all bytes in '\xFF' view?

---

**updating**:

I need representation in '\xFF' view to write this data to a file (I'm opening file with 'wb') as:

```
«hЏІPљ©Ш\#›]бmХWЦG}м#Ї†тЄЅm;>'Џщ
```

---

**update2**

Sorry for bothering. An answer lies under my nose all the time:

```
data_output = data_input.decode('hex')
write_file(filename, data_output)  #just opens a file 'wb', ant write a data in it
```

gives the same result as I need

Comment: You appear to be confusing the *Python representation* with the contents. Python merely gives you ASCII characters where the bytes can be interpreted as such. `\x68` is the ASCII codepoint for the letter `a`, so Python presents you with that as such. Why do you *have* to have it printed as `\x68` instead?

Comment: If you print the `data_output` value *as specified*, it'll print **exactly the same way** as the output of `data_input.decode('hex')`. In other words, `data_output == data_input.decode('hex')` is *True*. Did you want to output *literal backslashes and `x` characters plus two hex characters* instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters FWIW, `\x68` is the `h` not the `a`.

Comment: @sebastian: ah, yes, of course.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Mike. Your question is somewhat unclear, but could be made much more clear if you'd provide a complete sample program. Please create a short, complete program that demonstrates the  problem you are having. Please include the output you see and the output you desire. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://SSCCE.org for more info.

Comment: Related: [What is the meaning of the letters in the output from struct.pack?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12242870) and [Difference between different hex types/representations in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13123877)

Answer (score 2):

I like chopping strings into fixed-width chunks using `re.findall`

```
print '\\x' + '\\x'.join(re.findall('.{2}', data_input))
```

If you want to actually convert the string into a list of ints, you can do that like this:

```
data = [int(x, 16) for x in re.findall('.{2}', data_input)]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an inefficient solution, but there's always:

```
flag = True
data_output = ''
for char in data_input:
    if flag:
        buffer = char
        flag = False
    else:
        data_output = data_output + '\\x' + buffer + char
        flag = True
```

EDIT HOPEFULLY THE LAST: Who knew I could mess up in so many different ways on that simple a loop? Should actually run now...

Comment: I'm getting `NameError: name 'true' is not defined` on the first line.

Comment: @Kevin My bad, forgot boolean capitalization (working on java in another tab, confused myself)

Comment: Im not the down vote ... but this is not the ideal solution ... unless this output is just for you to look at... and not for you to use

Comment: I'm aware it's non-ideal, but it should function, which is better than nothing.

Comment: There are far more efficient ways to produce the output with literal `\x` characters, but it isn't even clear what the OP wants here.

Comment: A different take on the same solution: `''.join(['\\x'+x+y for x,y in zip(data_output[::2], data_output[1::2])])`

Comment: A different different take: `"".join("\\x{:2X}".format(ord(c)) for c in data_input.decode("hex"))`

Comment: Thanks for algorithm but it wont do in my case (see update). If I `ll use your code than in a file will be \\xAB\\x68\\x8F\\xB2\\x50\\x9A\..... not «hЏІPљ©Ш

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> int('0x10AFCC', 16)
1093580
>>> hex(1093580)
'0x10afcc'
```

So prepend your string with '0x' then do the above